# How to enter Vi / Vim command mode with `;` instead of `:`?

Tags: vim, vi, key-binding, bindings

When using Vi or Vim,
I need to perform the following sequence to save a file: `esc + :s`

But the `:` key is hard to reach on my keyboard. So I would like to switch `:` and `;` so that I can type `esc + ;s` to save the file.

(I'm looking for a solution that works with every commands, not only to save a file)

Comment: So why are you asking in a very specific manner for VI/VIM? You could try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices) to switch them around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nnoremap ; :
```

See also [`:help map`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html).

Comment: You will want to supplement that with the inverse `nnoremap : ;` so you still have the original functionality of `;` available.